# Margin Top on Scroll is not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code.  on Scroll height is working, but margin-top is not working. Any idea how to resolve this issue

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>300){
        // animate fixed div to small size:
        $('.secHead a.views').animate({marginTop:"-14px"});
        $('.listTrigger').stop().animate({ height: 45 });

    } else {
        //  animate fixed div to original size

        $('.listTrigger').stop().animate({ height: 82 });

    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that your element with margin-top: -14px works fine.

Then, try replacing this:

```
$('.secHead a.views').animate({marginTop:"-14px"});
```

By this:

```
$('.secHead a.views').animate({'margin-top:"-14px"});
```